# Moonmail installation issue - Command "project" not found

Tags: serverless-framework, moonmail

I'm initializing Moonmail and following the readme, executing the following command:

```
sls project init -c -n your-lower-case-project-name
```

I'm getting the following:

```
Command "project" not found, Run "serverless help" for...
```

It seems that Serverless no longer has the "project" command (since version 0.5) and it has been replaced with "service" (which works a little differently).

What would be the way forward here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [they say](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail) that Moonmail supports *version 0.5.2 or higher*, it's [not true](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/issues/157). You need to use version 0.5x of the Serverless Framework and you can't use any version 1.x because 1.x is a complete rewrite.

Unfortunately, the solution is to uninstall the current Serverless Framework and install an old version.

```
npm -g uninstall serverless  
npm -g install serverless@0.5.6
```

Comment: How difficult would it be to modify the repository to support Serverless 1.x? Is there a straightforward way? Otherwise, is there a way to switch back-and-forth with a global NPM package?

Comment: [Migrating from 0.5x to 1.0x](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/v0_to_v1/) is possible, but not straightforward. You need to understand both versions and adjust the settings. Regarding having multiples versions of the same module, I believe that [it is not possible](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499).